# kubernetes schedule job after cron

Tags: kubernetes, cron, jobs

I have Cron name "cronX" and a Job name "JobY"
how can I configure kubernetes to run "JobY" after "cronX" finished?

I know I can do it using API call from "cronX" to start "JobY" but I don't want to do that using an API call.

Is there any Kubernetes configuration to schedule this?

Comment: does it have to be in a different container or does init container will do the trick ?

Comment: can you please provide more detail about how to solve it with 'init container' ? so I will know if its an option?

Comment: when cron schedule time arrived,  it's create a pod, right? is it possible that this pod will contain 2 containers and one of them will run only after the second container finish?

Answer (score 1):

`is it possible that this pod will contain 2 containers and one of them will run only after the second container finish?`

Negative, more details [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1996). If you only have 2 containers to run, you can place the first one under `initContainers` and another under `containers` and schedule the pod.

No built-in K8s configuration available to do workflow orchestration. You can try Argo [workflow](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cron-workflows/) to do this.